# Error in Spring 4 | java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting below error while executing spring 4 application, could you please help me ?

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4932)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5218)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.anandc.webmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>MVC_Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring4MVCWebApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.20</freemarker.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.security.taglib.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.security.taglib.version>
        <spring.jdbc.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.jdbc.version>
        <common.logging.version>1.1.1</common.logging.version>
        <servlet.api.version>3.0.1</servlet.api.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JUnit dependencies Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit dependencies End -->

        <!-- FTL dependencies Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FTL dependencies End -->

        <!-- Spring dependencies Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies End -->
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.taglib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - END -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${common.logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>Spring4MVCWebApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> This is how my web.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Freemarker_SpringMVC_example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

> This is how my spring-servlet.xml looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- freemarker config -->
    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
      <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
      View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
      different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.
    -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
      <property name="cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="prefix" value=""/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.anandc" />

</beans>
```

Also, please suggest if I need any cleanups in my POM when I am using Spring 4.

Thank you in advance !

Please Note -
I have gone through the existing similar questions, However none of those help.

Regards,
[Anand Chavan](http://www.anandc.me)

Comment: Please Note- I am using eclipse Luna with Jdk 8.0 and tomcat 8.0

Comment: For starters fix your dependencies. `spring-jdbc` should be he same version as the spring framework (you are now mixing spring 4.0.2 and 4.0.5). For spring security it is even worse you are mixing version 3.2 and 3.0. Spring Security Taglib is part of spring security it should match the version number.

Comment: The hint to solve this exception is: ensure that `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` is available on the classpath. In other words: make sure that the `spring-webmvc.jar` is available in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Based on the pom.xml it should be there, but the Exception says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:
1, Change spring-servlet.xml:

```
FROM    

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>

TO <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
```

2, If you put your jar on **Libraries**, you try to put those jar to **WEB-INF/lib**

I solve this problem by means of the method above.
But I don't really know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try the trick below, it works for me every time:

1. Select the project and go to **Properties > Deployment Assembly**
2. Click on **Add**
3. Select **Java Build Path Entries**
4. If in there exists any Maven Dependencies, select all (Ctrl+A) and click **Finish**
5. Clean and refresh your project

Publish and try to start your server now,

Hope this help,
Best Regards,

Comment: whats intellij equivalent of this?