# Spring MVC integration js and css files

Tags: javascript, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new with Spring Framework, this is my first app using it, so, I have the next problem.. And I'm sorry for my really bad english hehe..

I need to include in my jsp some js and css files. I'm working with spring mvc. I have a NotClassFound exception.. This is all my code:

In my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResouceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In servlet-context (I've tried with mvc resource with and without "classpath")

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/"/> -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

in the jsp file

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.js.resource.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/medico.css'/>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/zapdent.js"></script>
<%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />"> </script> --%>
</head>
```

In 'webapp/resources' is where I have my js and ccs files.. and I think my principal problem is with the org.springframework.js library.. I'm mapping it in the web.xml, but when I run the project I have this:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /springsecurity threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.js.resource.ResouceServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4944)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have like a week trying to figure out this problem, but I dont know how to do it.. Please, I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need ResourceServlet. The mvc:resources tag alone will do the trick. the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/webflow/2.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/js/resource/ResourceServlet.html) is explicit and clear: It's deprecated in favor of the resource tag. Don't use them both

Answer (score 0):

Looking at web.xml it seems that  `org.springframework.js.resource.ResouceServlet` should be there, but make sure it exists in the classpath. You could also try following this link and perform these steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170853/2748793

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! The solution in the link didn't work.. But, how can I be sure that the class exist in the classpath? I'm sorry, I'm new.. I have it in the Referenced Libraries. Thank you for the answer!!